# Stretch or Taut a fabric with Cloth Simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have a problem with cloth simulation.
I want stretch a fabric between 3 points, so I did an pin group with some vertices but it seems to be more saggy than stretched...

[image]

I tried to represent with this schema what I would like to do, as if the fabric were stretched by the 3 points

[image]

Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: 1) either increase the *Shrink* value a bit (try 0.1) -or 2) stretch it with animated hooks or an animated shape key. Then run it together with the cloth simulation.